# Crystal Report viewer just shows lines in IE; exports data to PDF fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I've created a very simple report just to test the way to connect to it with ASP.net. It appears to be loading the report and pulling the report data from the database without any problems, but what is displayed is just a bunch of vertical lines. If I choose to export to PDF, etc., via the toolbar, however, that appears fine. Checking the source code of the page also reveals that the data is present there.

Here is the image result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Rbg.png

And here is my code:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
  ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
  report.Load(@"C:\Users\en\Desktop\Crystal Reports\report1.rpt");
  report.SetDatabaseLogon("xxx", "xxx", @"xxx", "xxx");
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
}
```

And in the aspx:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="903px" DisplayToolbar="False" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
          <Report FileName="C:\Users\ben\Desktop\Crystal Reports\Report1.rpt">
           </Report>
         </CR:CrystalReportSource>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I found some documentation that shows IE is the issue, and confirmed by checking and seeing that it works fine in Chrome. It also works in IE compatibility mode. The users will be in IE; does anybody know a way to make IE display this correctly from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up turning on IE7 emulation mode, as documented here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1472369.aspx/1

It feels like a poor fix, but seems to work just fine.